What's the transimpedance gain in this common-gate stage?
The following is from the book RF MICROELECTRONICS Page 47.
Calculate the input-referred noise of the common-gate stage depicted in Fig. 2.46(a).
Assume I1 is ideal and neglect the noise of \$R_1\$.

Defined as the output voltage divided by the input current, the transimpedance gain of the
stage is given \$g_m r_O R_1\$.
The author hasn't explained how he derive this transimpedance gain.

$$V_x = I_{in} R_1$$
$$\frac{V_{out} - V_x} {r_O} - V_x g_{m1} = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = R_1 \biggl( 1 + g_{m1} r_O \biggl)$$
However, we have differences.
Who is correct?
